# Sql Server Management Studio Object Explorer disappeared - missing - vanished

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The SQL Server Management Studio `Object Explorer` menu disappeared. The shortcut `F8` and the `view->object explorer` method neither do anything. I have clicked everything on the keyboard, googled around, but nothing.

I really need this back, it's a massive hassle having to navigate through the summary window without the object explorer tree view!

Comment: A few things:  when you created your project, what did you put in for Authentication Type?  If you put in "none" it won't allow you to connect with SQL, so... no point in including the SQL Object Explorer window.  With that said, you still might be able to force it with Cntrl + \ Cntrl + S.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I just had this, and the menu option...

Window > Reset Window Layout

...worked a treat.

Comment: For me after this I had to do, `window` -> `auto hide all`, and then, `view` -> `other windows` -> `sql server object explorer`.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this same problem when double-clicking on a SQL file when SSMS is not already open.  When this happens, an SSMS console gets opened automatically, but none of the windows are present, and some of them cannot be enabled.  To avoid this, simply open SSMS first, and THEN click on the SQL file you were trying to open.

Comment: Brilliant! thats what I was looking for. It happened with me after updating SSMS package to 2.0.4.0. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Tools --> Options --> Keyboard --> Keyboard --> Top Drop Down list click change from (Default) to the other one such as Visual Studio 2010 Compatible. Click ok.

After this options settings is edited and F8 is pressed the object explorer will open.

[image]

Stellar question. One option is to edit the Keyboard Options within SQL Server Management Studio.

Hope that helps people!

Answer (score 2):

[Windows] -> [Auto Hide] helped me

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it isn't actually somewhere else on screen (i.e. has been clicked and dragged somewhere else?)