# SignalR perfectly run on local database but throws exception on server database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

My code (SignalR) perfectly runs on a local database when I am trying to use with server database, I get an exception.

Code is here: 
https://github.com/mewanindula/SignalR-SQL_Dependency

**Exception** :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot find the object "QueryNotificationErrorsQueue" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

How to resolve this exception?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the database through **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**? If so go to the *Management node* and *Sql Server Logs* and there you can see if there are any errors logged when you try to access the database:

[image: SQL Server logs img]

The errors that are logged can give you a much better error description to solve your problem.

Comment: I can't see a 'Management' tree menu

Comment: It could be hidden due to security reasons. What version MSSQL are you running?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio - 15.0.18333.0

Comment: Check out the following stackoverflow Q&A. Looks like others have had similar propblems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945960/sql-server-management-studio-object-explorer-disappeared-missing-vanished